# for row in table , save the row in temporary table to use its data in select query in plpgsql

Tags: for-loop, iteration, row, plpgsql

I want to do something like this , but not sure will **the row variable of data type record**  used to **iterate a for loop over a table** can be **inserted into a temporary table** within the same for loop itself,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LoopThroughTable() 
RETURNS VOID 
AS
$$
DECLARE 
t_row record;
BEGIN
   FOR t_row in SELECT * FROM the_table
      LOOP
      create temp table tmp as (select * from t_row); --- is this possible??
      --- use the data of tmp table in some select query
      drop table tmp; -- is this possible??
      END LOOP;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If it is possible, can someone help me with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Just in case someone stumbles upon this post, the efficient way of accessing **t_row record** kind of data would be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LoopThroughTable() 
RETURNS VOID 
AS
$$
DECLARE 
   t_row record;
BEGIN
   FOR t_row in SELECT * FROM table_1
       LOOP
          SELECT * FROM table_2 when A= t_row.B 
          -- where A is a column in table_2 whose value should be equal to column B in t_row (which single row from table_1) 
       END LOOP;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```